# 2 ec2 instance interacting with each other

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am new to aws and ec2 interaction with traffic flow.

I have one ec2 instance which I am using as a web server and other as an application server.
how can my two ec2 interact with each other maintaining all the security required?

Both the ec2 machines are on the ubuntu image.

I tried adding All ICMP - IPv4 with source 0.0.0.0/0. I feel it's not the correct way I want only my other instance to access it.

I also tried adding source as other instance security group but didn't work. I was not able to ping from one machine to other

Comment: Are they in same subnet?

Comment: @muasif80 yes they are in the same subnet

Comment: then whats the issue you are facing? share the error log or error message? how are you trying to connect to the other instance? on which protocol? http or ssh? are the security groups allowing traffic for ssh or http the protocol you are using.

Comment: I have all the port ssh, HTTP, and https open on both the instance.
when I ssh into the machine1 and run "pin public ipv4 of another match", didn't work couldn't connect to machine2.
then I added inbound rule in machine 2 with All ICMP - IPv4 with source 0.0.0.0/0. 
I was able to ping from machine one to two. 
BUT I felt it's not safe.
Then I used All ICMP - IPv4 with a source security group of machine 1, after which I was not able to ping

Comment: It sounds like you are connecting to Machine 2 (App server) via a public IP address rather than a private IP address.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yes I was using the elastic IP address. Could you guide me to best practice?

Comment: When communicating between instances within the same VPC, always communicate via **private IP addresses**. This keeps the traffic within the VPC, reduces costs (there is a 1c/GB charge if it goes out of the VPC and comes back in) and allows it to work with references to other security groups.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended security configuration would be:

- Create a Security Group for the web server (`Web-SG`) that permits Inbound traffic for HTTP and HTTPS (ports 80, 443). Leave the Outbound configuration as the default "Allow All".
- Create a Security Group for the app server (`App-SG`) that permits Inbound traffic from `Web-SG` on the desired ports. Leave the Outbound configuration as the default "Allow All".

That is, `App-SG` should specifically refer to `Web-SG` in the Inbound rules. This will permit traffic from `Web-SG` to enter `App-SG`.

You might want to add additional access so that you can manage the instances (eg SSH), or you can use AWS Systems Manager Session Manager to connect.

Do not use Ping to test access since that requires additional settings and only proves that Ping works. Instead, test the actual access on the desired ports (eg port 80).

Comment: thank you for the answer. I am following the same thing which you have mentioned in the answer. To test access I was using ping. How else can I test the access?

Comment: I normally recommend _not_ to use Ping, because it requires additional ICMP ports to be opened, and all it does it prove that ping works. If your web server can't talk to the app server, confirm that it is using a Private IP address to communicate and confirm that the app server is listening on its port (eg `curl localhost:port` on the app server).

Comment: I have apache running on the webserver which wants to access the dotnet application on the app server.
dotnet runs on port 5000 so I should add port 5000 and source security group of the webserver. If I understood it right